# Send JSON response from helper to #create in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, reactjs, axios

Having some issues putting these puzzle pieces together... I'm scraping a website to get an array of strings and I want the array to get sent back to my React client for use. Here's what I have

**index.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { restaurant } = this.state

    axios.post('/api/scraper', { restaurant: restaurant })
    .then((res) => {
         console.log(res.data);
    })
}
```

**app/controllers/api/scraper_controller.rb**

```
class Api::ScraperController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def create
        @info = helpers.get_info(params[:restaurant])
        respond_with @info
    end

end
```

**app/helpers/api/scraper_helper.rb**

```
module Api::ScraperHelper

    def get_info(restaurant)
        puts restaurant

        require 'openssl'
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.subway.com/en-us/menunutrition/menu/all', :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))

        @items = []
        doc.css('.menu-cat-prod-title').each do |item|
            @items.push(item.text)
        end
    end

end
```

The whole idea is to get the `@items` array sent back to my `axios` request on my React page

Comment: Did you try adding `@items` as the last line withing the `get_info` method to be returned? or to using `Array#map`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I tried adding `respond_with @items` in my `get_info` function but I was getting an `undefined method` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual code will just return 0, because the result of applying `each` in a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` in this case is 0, and is what you're leaving as the last executed "piece of code" within your method, so Ruby will return this.

If you add @items in the last line, then this will be returned, and you'll get `["Black Forest Ham", "Chicken & Bacon Ranch Melt", ...]` that I guess is what you need:

```
@items = []
doc.css('.menu-cat-prod-title').each { |item| @items.push(item.text) }
@items
```

Note you could also do a map operation on `doc.css('.menu-cat-prod-title')`, which can then be assigned to any instance variable:

```
def get_info(restaurant)
  ...
  doc.css('.menu-cat-prod-title').map(&:text)
end
```

I guess to return the data from create you could use something like `render json: { items: @items }`, as items contains an array of menues.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I'm getting a `nil` response with your `render json: { items: @items }` however, which I fixed for now by doing: `render json: { items: helpers.get_info(params[:restaurant]) }`

Comment: Glad to help, I just tried in a "plain" ruby file, maybe because of the lack of inputs.